# fail result when i convert java code to c++ code

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk, convolution

i convert Convolution class from java to c++ but result is wrong.
i use convolution to apply image filter with kernel :

```
{ -1 ,  0, -1 },
{  0 ,  4,  0 },
{ -1 ,  0, -1 }
```

orginal code in java:

```
public static Bitmap computeConvolution3x3(Bitmap src, ConvolutionMatrix matrix)     {
    int width = src.getWidth();
    int height = src.getHeight();
    Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, src.getConfig());

    int A, R, G, B;
    int sumR, sumG, sumB;
    int[][] pixels = new int[SIZE][SIZE];

    for(int y = 0; y < height - 2; ++y) {
        for(int x = 0; x < width - 2; ++x) {

            // get pixel matrix
            for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i) {
                for(int j = 0; j < SIZE; ++j) {
                    pixels[i][j] = src.getPixel(x + i, y + j);
                }
            }

            // get alpha of center pixel
            A = Color.alpha(pixels[1][1]);

            // init color sum
            sumR = sumG = sumB = 0;

            // get sum of RGB on matrix
            for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i) {
                for(int j = 0; j < SIZE; ++j) {
                    sumR += (Color.red(pixels[i][j]) * matrix.Matrix[i][j]);
                    sumG += (Color.green(pixels[i][j]) * matrix.Matrix[i][j]);
                    sumB += (Color.blue(pixels[i][j]) * matrix.Matrix[i][j]);
                }
            }

            // get final Red
            R = (int)(sumR / matrix.Factor + matrix.Offset);
            if(R < 0) { R = 0; }
            else if(R > 255) { R = 255; }

            // get final Green
            G = (int)(sumG / matrix.Factor + matrix.Offset);
            if(G < 0) { G = 0; }
            else if(G > 255) { G = 255; }

            // get final Blue
            B = (int)(sumB / matrix.Factor + matrix.Offset);
            if(B < 0) { B = 0; }
            else if(B > 255) { B = 255; }

            // apply new pixel
            result.setPixel(x + 1, y + 1, Color.argb(A, R, G, B));
        }
    }

    // final image
    return result;
}
```

and converted c++ code:
in c++ i use int* instead of bitmap that contain image data

```
int* ConvolutionMatrix::procImage() {
int sumR = 0;
int sumG = 0;
int sumB = 0;
int **_pixels = new int*[SIZE];
for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i) {
    _pixels[i] = new int[SIZE];
}
for (int y = 0; y < this->height - 2; ++y) {
    for (int x = 0; x < this->width - 2; ++x) {

        // get pixel matrix
        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; ++j) {
                int index = (y + j) * width + (x + i);
                _pixels[i][j] = this->pixels[index];
            }
        }
        // init color sum
        sumR = sumG = sumB = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; ++j) {
                Color color1(_pixels[i][j]);
                sumR += ( color1.R() * this->Matrix[i][j] );
                sumG += ( color1.G() * this->Matrix[i][j] );
                sumB += ( color1.B() * this->Matrix[i][j] );
            }
        }
        // get final Red
        int R = (int) (sumR / Factor + Offset);
        if (R < 0) {
            R = 0;
        } else if (R > 255) {
            R = 255;
        }
        // get final Green
        int G = (int) (sumG / Factor + Offset);
        if (G < 0) {
            G = 0;
        } else if (G > 255) {
            G = 255;
        }

        // get final Blue
        int B = (int) (sumB / Factor + Offset);
        if (B < 0) {
            B = 0;
        } else if (B > 255) {
            B = 255;
        }
        int index = ( y + 1 ) * width + ( x + 1 );
        //__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE,"Android Filter", "The Index is %d", index);
        this->pixels[index] = RGB2Color(R, G, B);
    }
}

return this->pixels;
```

}

but result's is:
Java Result :
[image]

c++ result:

[image]

where i mistake?

**EDIT**:

i guess found mistake

1)

```
  // get pixel matrix
        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; ++j) {
                int index = (x + i) * width + (y + j);
                _pixels[i][j] = this->pixels[index];
            }
        }
```

2)

```
int index = ( x + 1 ) * width + ( y + 1 );
            //__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE,"Android Filter", "The Index is %d", index);
this->pixels[index] = RGB2Color(R, G, B);
```

but now get error:

```
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xff975e1f (code=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, one problem is that you are mixing up the indexes in extracting the pixel matrix:

```
    // get pixel matrix
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; ++j) {
            int index = (y + j) * width + (x + i);
            _pixels[i][j] = this->pixels[index];
        }
    }
```

You're using `i` as the row-index and `j` as the column index for the `_pixels` array, but when computing your 1D index you are using `j` as the row index offset and `i` as the column index offset.

That might not be the only problem however -- what does the `RGB2Color` function look like?

Comment: static inline int RGB2Color(int r, int g, int b) {
 return 255 << 24 | r << 16 | g << 8 | b;
}

Comment: when i want access 1D array  formula is : row * width + col , and in java code col index x add row index i

Comment: in regards to the segfault, what line does it happen on?

Comment: complete error : 05-03 00:01:30.471: A/libc(17549): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xff975e1f (code=1), thread 17549 (.idin.timelapse)

Comment: Actually, looking at your edit, is that the code you're using now? That indexing is wrong. It has to be `row * width + col` in row-major languages. The initial error you had that I mentioned in my answer was that your indexing offsets were swapped. If you are indeed using the code in your edit, it'll segfault if your image width exceeds the height

Comment: @alikiani out of curiosity, did changing the indexing fix the segfaulting?